# ZeroMQ iOS attempt to call symbol that is not present in system libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, zeromq

I have compiled fat static library of ZeroMQ for archs: i386 armv7

I encountered a problem with zeromq and iOS6 like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500966/app-crashes-on-ios-6-symbol-not-found-sync-fetch-and-add-4)

So I decided to use 5.1 SDKs, I've downloaded xcode 4.3.3 and extracted 5.1 SDK to current XCode and set my project's base SDK and target SDK to 5.1

After I did this my project builds with no errors now, but when I call zmq_init(1) for example then I got this:

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries 
that is not present on the iPhone:
(null) called from function _ZN3zmq10signaler_t11make_fdpairEPiS1_
```

I have no idea how to fix it now. Is it a problem of SDKs or it's a problem of ZeroMq?

Update: problem occurs only with simulator

Comment: Is that `socketpair()` then?  Looks like an odd libc linking issue.

Comment: @Steve-o Your suggestion lead me to what I missed in configuration script. I specified -isysroot with iOS.simulator dir and now getting error in libsystem_c.dylib`strlen